# Slide-In menu: witdth and position:fixed

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, navigation

I've tried hours now to create a slide-in menu but still have a problem.

My menu should fulfill this points:

- just html & css (no js)
- change the icon on click
- full menu is visible if width > x (than no hamburger icon)
- sticky header
- responsive (mobile friendly)
- should work in modern browsers ;)

So that's what I've done so far:

```css
/* Micro reset */
*,*:before,*:after{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0;}
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

body {
  /* Without this, the body has excess horizontal scroll when the menu is open */
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1, h2, p {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  line-height: 2em;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 5em;
}
/* hb icon */

.menu-icon {
  padding: 28px 20px; /* better clickable > please consider in header */
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: #333;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: background .2s ease-out;
  width: 18px;
}

.menu-icon .navicon:before,
.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  background: #333;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  top: 5px;
}

.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  top: -5px;
}

/* Nav Trigger */

.nav-trigger {
  /* critical styles - hide the checkbox input */
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

label[for="nav-trigger"] {
  /* critical positioning styles */
  position: fixed;
  right: 15px; top: 15px;
  z-index: 3;

}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:before,
.nav-trigger:checked ~ .menu-icon:not(.steps) .navicon:after {
  top: 0;
}

/* Make the Magic Happen */
.nav-trigger + label, .site-wrap {
  transition: left 0.5s;
}

.nav-trigger + label {
  right: 15px;
  transition: right 0.5s;
}

.nav-trigger:checked + label {
  right: 215px;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .navigation {
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.nav-trigger:checked ~ .site-wrap {
  left: -200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}


/* Slider Menu - Background */
.navigation {
  /* critical sizing and position styles */
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index:-1;
  /* non-critical appearance styles */
  list-style: none;
  background: #F2F2F2;
}

ul.navigation {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 0 20px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul.navigation li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 12px 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid #f4f4f4;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.navigation li a:hover {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
}


@media (min-width: 51em) {
  ul.navigation li {
    float: left;
  }
  ul.navigation li a {
    padding: 20px 30px;
  }
  .navigation {
    clear: none;
    float: right;
    max-height: none;
  }
   .menu-icon, .navigation {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* Site Wrapper - Everything that isn't navigation */
.site-wrap {
  /* Critical position and size styles */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #999; /* Needs a background or else the nav will show through */
  /* non-critical apperance styles */
  background-size: 200%;
}

#hdr {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #CCC;
  min-width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.rofl {
  width:100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 28px 20px; /* follow from .menu-icon */
  background-color: #F00;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.menu {
  float:right;
  width:400px;
  background-color: #333;
}

.menu li {
  float:left;
}

.menu li a {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration:none;
}

@media (max-width: 50.99em) {
   .menu {
    display: none;
  }
}

.wrp {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  height:100%
}
```

```html
<link href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrp">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <input type="checkbox" class="nav-trigger" id="nav-trigger" />
  <label for="nav-trigger" class="menu-icon"><span class="navicon"></span></label>
  <div class="site-wrap">
    <div id="hdr">
      <div class="rofl">Header...
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="">Menu 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Menu 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <h2>Subline</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
    <p>Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Watch it on codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGwjXZ

Now the problem is that if the width is > 1600 the header (red) won't stop on the right side. (Maybe there are other problems too...)

Is there any trick to get a maximum width for the header too? If I delete "position: fixed;" in class rofl it works. But the header should be visible on scrolling.

Thank you for reading my question!
Bazi

Comment: There is a second problem on FF. If the hamburger icon is shown an I click it, the header has a wrong behaviour :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following:

```
.rofl {
  max-width: 1600px;
}
```

Having the max width addition to your css will stop it from exceeding the chosen width.